# why the code seems haven't executed when there is no output related?

Tags: performance, fortran

consider this Fortran program:

```
program main
implicit none

double complex :: a(51,51),b(51,51)
Integer::i,j
real(8)::ht=0.01
real(8) T1,T2

do i=1,51
   do j=1,51
      a(i,j)=cmplx(Sin(0.01*i),Cos(0.01*j))
   end do
end do

call cpu_time(T1)

do i=1,23497
   b(:,:)=(0.,1.)*ht/2.*a(:,:)
end do

call cpu_time(T2)

write(*,*) sum(b)
print '("Time = ",f12.9," seconds.")', T2-T1

end program main
```

the output is

```
 (-12.4321907340245,3.30723047182099)
Time =  0.052991000 seconds.
```

If we comment out the `write(*,*) sum(b)`, the output is

```
Time =  0.000000000 seconds.
```

it seems the loop is not executed, why this happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you remove the `write` statement, the compiler can see that the variable `b` is never used, so it removes the code that assigns `b`.

Once it has done that, it can then tell that the variable `a` is never used, either, so it removes the code that assigns that variable.

Then there's nothing left except the calls to `cpu_time()`.